# bash script array variables in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I am trying to write bash script that get 3 arguments of paths.
for ex /tmp/1 /tmp/2 /tmpnew
I want to iterate over the argument except the last one and each time copy the file to the path of the last argument.

I have problem with echo '${files[$(($len))]}' inside the for. I cant pull the last argument like that.

```
files=( "$@" )

len=${#files[@]}
echo $len
for (( i=0; i<$(( $len -1 )); i++ ))
    do
        echo ${files[$(($len))]}
        echo ${files[$i]}
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

The last element is `${files[len-1]}`, or simply `${files[-1]}`.

Similarly, you can use just `${files[i]}`. If the array is not associative, bash interprets the index as an arithmetic expression.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=("$@")

len=${#files[@]}
echo $len
for (( i=0; i<len-1; i++ )) ; do
    echo "${files[-1]}"
    echo "${files[i]}"
done
```